# Device List ( "Select Deployment target" ) populates very slowly now

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

In Android Studio, when I run an app, it pops up this dialog titled "Select Deployment Target" ( the one where you pick which device or emulator to run the app on).

Before I can see the list of devices and emulators, there's a loading screen with the text "Looking for virtual devices".

This loading screen used to be visible for only a short moment, now, I since one of the latest updates to Android Studio ( I'm running 3.2.1 ), this can take a few seconds.

How to speed up this wait time?